# how to calculate resume and pause data amount in progress bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

How can I calculate received data after I pause and resume a function.

I'm working on file download, including download pause and resume.

It pauses ok, but when I resume it, it doesn't go to 100%. it stops before 100%

```
  function download_file(event, filename) {
          req2 = request({
            method: 'GET',
            uri: fileURL
          });
            var out = fs.createWriteStream(finalPath);
            req2.pipe(out);
            req2.on('response', function(data) {
total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
    progressBar.max = total_bytes;
    total_size = total_bytes;
            });
            req2.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    received_bytes += chunk.length;
 console.log(received_bytes);
progressBar.value = received_bytes;
display.innerText = Math.round((progressBar.value / progressBar.max) * 1000) / 10 + '%'
              }
            });
        };

    function pause22() {
      console.log('pause function called');
      req2.pause();
    }

        function resume22() {
          console.log('RESUME function called');
 progressBar.max=progressBar.max-progressBar.value;
  console.log(progressBar.max);
  console.log(progressBar.value);
   progressBar.value = received_bytes;
   received_bytes= progressBar.value;
  req2.resume();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to continue where you left off in the download and that you are storing 'total_bytes' and 'received_bytes' as global variables then your progress bar would simply re-establish to those. Your resume22 should be...

```
function resume22() {
      console.log('RESUME function called');
      progressBar.max=total_bytes;
      console.log(progressBar.max);
      progressBar.value = received_bytes;
      console.log(progressBar.value);
      req2.resume();
    }
```

Comment: yes, that's what I exactly want!, first thank you for your answer!, sadly your code doesn't work.. when i pause at 11% and resume 1minute later it ends at 36%..

Comment: Does it start off at 11% after you have pause it at 11% ?  Also I am wondering if there is buffering on the download stream that impacts the perceived progress. Check the global variables as you enter Pause function to make sure they are what you expect.